Fixing alpine (node) base image vulnerability
I am using a docker image created from base node:22-alpine3.19. It shows vulnerability for the following packages :
3.19:ssl_client     1.36.1-r15 , fixed in 1.36.1-r25 [CVE-2023-42366]
3.19:busybox        1.36.1-r15 , fixed in 1.36.1-r25 [CVE-2023-42366]
3.19:busybox-binsh  1.36.1-r15 , fixed in1.36.1-r25  [CVE-2023-42366] 

Seems these are fixed in 3.19.1 .
I tried to update & upgrade the alpine packages in my Dockerfile. The created docker image still shows these vulnerability. How can I patch these.
Dockerfile :
FROM node:${RUNTIME_VERSION}-alpine${DISTRO_VERSION} AS builder

ARG FUNCTION_DIR
WORKDIR ${FUNCTION_DIR}

RUN apk add --no-cache \
    libstdc++ \
:
    libcurl \
    python3

RUN apk update  #Tried update/upgrade in build stage
RUN apk upgrade --no-cache
<Install my dependencies>


#  Production Stage
FROM node:${RUNTIME_VERSION}-alpine${DISTRO_VERSION}

RUN apk update    #Tried update/upgrade in production stage
RUN apk upgrade --no-cache

ARG FUNCTION_DIR

WORKDIR ${FUNCTION_DIR}

COPY --from=builder ${FUNCTION_DIR}/node_modules ${FUNCTION_DIR}/node_modules

I tried adding apk update/upgrade both in builder and production stages but I am unable to affect the final docker image which still shows the vulnerability.
How can I patch my image to fix these vulnerabilities /upgrade to 3.19.1 alpine.
Thanks

"Seems these are fixed in 3.19.1 ." then just rebuild your image on 3.19.1?  Why do you have to fix them yourself if that's the case?  Looks to me like they're only fixed starting in r-25

Thank you. Yes these are fixed in 3.19.1 (hence I tried update/upgrade(, but I am using node (alpine) image which has 3.19. So should I re-create node image or can I update the packages within the current node image is my question. How do I "re-build" my image (Dockerfile provided)

node:22-alpine3.19 was updated yesterday, so do docker pull node:22-alpine3.19 and rebuild your image and it should be fixed.

I tested with node:22-alpine3.19, it still shows the same vulnerabilities. I also tried patching from alpine to create node image from - https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/cab20530fe21ce8989854152060591c83a6a7806/22/alpine3.19/Dockerfile , replacing the base with alpine3.19.1 and running apk update and upgrade. But still same issue. I have only worked on application layer so not sure if I am trying to patch it right.

I was facing the same issue with node:20.14-alpine3.20 AS base and this two  CVE-2023-42364 and CVE-2023-42365 are not fixed even with latest image and bug is open at image.
For a workaround i had used RUN apk update && apk add busybox=1.36.1-r29 in my dockerfile and its worked as expected.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
